# Loading a HTML page from webfoot folder of apache server - newbie

Tags: php, html, apache, web

As the tittle says I'm new to all concepts of networkiing and web development.

Yesterday I was able to set up a Local Apache Server which I am using for development testing purposes.

I have assigned for a Server the ServerName "client1.dev" with a VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/client1/wwwroot", yet it is unclear for me how I am supposed to link my HTML page.

I am currently stuck at the point where all my files when accessing the domain appear under a plain list format from which I can select my files which will eventually load the HMTL content of choosing.

Since I'm a total beginner in this domain and I've got a hard time even googling the right questions. I'd like to know how I could instantly when accessing the server name domain to load a given HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the Apache HTTP server will look for a file named `index.html` in the directory that is displayed. If it finds such a file, the `index.html` will be displayed. Otherwise it falls back to list the contents of the directory (but that could be changed to disallow directory listings).

If you do not have an `index.html` file in the directory, the easiest solution would be to create one.

If you want to display another file by default, then you can change that in the Apache configuration. Use the [`DirectoryIndex` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) to do that. A basic example that changes the index files for the `/foo` directory looks like this:

```
# Example A: Set index.html as an index page,
# then add index.php to that list as well.
<Directory "/foo">
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>

# Example B: This is identical to example A,
# except it's done with a single directive.
<Directory "/foo">
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example which puts both the .html and .php @ the Directory Index.

Answer (score 0):

The default page you want to make appear when accessing the root directory in your browser should be named "index.php" (I am supposing you are running PHP)